# b bar similar to h bar

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I would like to know if there is a `$\bbar$` command to produce the symbol

[image]

just as there is a `$\hbar$` command for the symbol

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I would just look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96479/121799) and try to replace `\labda` by `b`.

Comment: I already tried `\bbar`, did not work

Comment: I see, I have to declare the command, now it works thank you.