# how can I create q bar symbol in math mode just like \hbar?

Tags: math-mode

I need create a new math symbol a q with a bar just like command \hbar (h with a bar)

Thanks for your help, this is an example

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,]{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,calculator}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nicefrac}% UNIDADES SI
\usepackage{units}% UNIDADES SI
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,bending}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,polar} %
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,polar}


\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{fourier} % math font

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Arial}


\begin{document}
    

This is the document

$\left(x+a\right)^2$, I need a $q$ command with bar 



\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, go to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96482/59109) and just replace `lambda` with `q`. You might want to further fine tune the height to suit `q`.

Comment: [Avoid `commath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=commath+user%3A4427); I don't see how `units` helps as you're loading `siunitx`. Your preamble is full of contradictory calls: why `txfonts` if you're later loading `fourier`? And are you sure that `fourier` math fonts are compatible with Arial as the main text font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the math font you're using.

With Computer Modern, taking the cue from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551356/4427, but also from the fact that the bar is at a different position, namely `\mathchar '26`, we can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\addbar@}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \raisebox{#1}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \kern#2
      $\m@th\mathchar'26$%
    }%
  }%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\qbar}{\text{\addbar@{-1.5ex}{0.01em}}q}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Normal size $q\ne \qbar$ and subscript $X_{q}\ne X_{\qbar}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the `fourier` math fonts, the code should be modified, because they don't have the required bar in the expected place. I'll solve this by horizontally scaling a minus sign.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\addbar@}[3]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \raisebox{#1}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \kern#2
      \scalebox{0.6}[1]{$\m@th-$}%
    }%
  }%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\qbar}{\text{\addbar@{-0.8ex}{0.2em}{1}}q}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Normal size $q\ne \qbar$ and subscript $X_{q}\ne X_{\qbar}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Im using as math font fourier from fourier package and Im using LuaLatex too...

Comment: Yes, but How can I do this q when Im Using Fourier font in LuaLatex

Comment: @AlejandroMunozOssa I stated at the outset that this depends on the fonts. Please, add a minimal version of your document preamble, limited to the font setup.

Comment: I added a code like you told me, thanks for the help

Comment: @AlejandroMunozOssa I added the workaround.